# Select2 tags allow use space on it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

I wanna make my tags have space, live `ketchup v2` but for now it's generating two tags `ketchup` and `v2`.
I took the simple example of making tags or search for existed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%;"></select>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $('.select2').select2({
            data: ["Piano", "Flute", "Guitar", "Drums", "Photography"],
            tags: true,
            maximumSelectionLength: 10,
            tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
            placeholder: "Select or type keywords",
            //minimumInputLength: 1,
            //ajax: {
           //   url: "you url to data",
           //   dataType: 'json',
            //  quietMillis: 250,
            //  data: function (term, page) {
            //     return {
            //         q: term, // search term
            //    };
           //  },
           //  results: function (data, page) { 
           //  return { results: data.items };
          //   },
          //   cache: true
           // }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So, I want to do only with enter create a tag, not with space or something like that.

Comment: You meant Select2, not bootstrap.  And that's just how the plugin works, each selected option will be a separate "tag" in the box. They are separate elements, but you might be able to override the CSS to make them look combined as one.

Comment: But, then im intert another tag , it will be combined as one or not?

Comment: It will only appear as one.  if you want multiple options to be combined as a single answer, best to do that on the values after submission.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this and check.

```
tokenSeparators: [',']
```

This will allow only enter key or comma to create a tag.